# Not able to show JSON data using Ember-Model

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-model

I have started using Ember Model, but the JSON data is not getting loaded into the view. Moreover, I am not getting errors or warnings on console.

Here's my app.js,

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate : function(controller) {
         this.render('MyTemplate', {
             controller : 'Index'

        });
    },
    model : function() {
        return App.MyTemplateModel.find();
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});


App.MyTemplateModel = Ember.Model.extend({
    id : Ember.attr(),
    last_name : Ember.attr(),
    first_name : Ember.attr(),
    suffix : Ember.attr(),
    expiration : Ember.attr()
});

App.MyTemplateModel.url = "http://ankur1.local/index.php/api/example/users/";
App.MyTemplateModel.adapter = Ember.RESTAdapter.create();
var existing = App.MyTemplateModel.find();
App.MyTemplateModel.camelizeKeys = true;
```

and Here's my HTML,

```
<body>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="myTemplate">
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name!"/>
            <button {{action clickButton}} >Button</button>
            {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="userName"}}

            <label >{{userName}}</label>

            {{#each item in model}}
            <tr><td>
            {{id}} <small> {{item.first_name}}</small>
            </td></tr>
            {{/each}}
        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
            <h1>Application Template</h1>
            {{outlet}}
        </script>

    </body>
```

What I might be missing in my code?

Moreover, I can get individual values on the console using,

```
var u = App.MyTemplateModel.find(1); 
u.get('first_name');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `render` or `{{render}}` helper you are rendering with a different controller. You have to provide it the model to use. Try changing to,

```
renderTemplate : function(controller) {
    this.render('myTemplate', {
        controller : controller
    });
},
```

Here `controller` is the controller for `IndexRoute` ie:- `IndexController` which was populated with the `model` hooks.

### Edit: Post jsbin

You are using `MyTemplateModel` to loop over the items in your view. You need to loop over `content`, `model` or `controller` which all correspond to the model backing that route.

```
{{#each item in content }}
  <tr><td>
  {{item.id}} <p> {{item.first_name}}</p>
  </td></tr>
{{/each}}
```

Other than that you may need to declare the `rootKey` and `collectionKey` on the model to get ember-model to recognize your json response correctly.

```
App.MyTemplateModel.rootKey = 'user';
App.MyTemplateModel.collectionKey = 'users';
```

Here's an updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eciviv/1/edit).

Comment: Can you explain me in bit more detail? I think I have done the same thing.

Comment: You are passing in `Index` to the controller which results in a lookup via Ember IOC container, and gives a different controller. In the answer, I am passing forward the same controller from the `renderTemplate` argument forward to the `render` method.

Comment: No change :( I edited code a bit few hours ago, can you have a look again?

Comment: Hard to tell, try uploading a jsbin with the problem. You can use something like mockjax to simulate the server result.

Comment: No, I am talking about the code in the question, can you have a look?

Comment: I did, But if you put up a [jsbin](http://www.jsbin.com) it would be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: My apologies, I should have noticed the error in your template earlier. See my updated answer.

Comment: That was it! :O Thanks you so much for helping out! :)

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do to get it to work was specify no root in my JSON serializer. In other words, instead of...

```
{
  MyTemplateModel:
  {
    id: 1,
    etc...
  }
}
```

It looks like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  etc....
}
```

I can only assume that since ember-model already expects the model `MyTemplateModel` as a response that it doesn't look for that in the JSON. Hope this helps.